Копирование цвета фона диапазона ячеек Таблиц Гугла из диапазона на другом листе по результатам вычисления формулой
Я создал специальную таблицу, в которой изложил суть задачи и в которой прошу публиковать предложения её решения:
В наиболее общем виде задача формулируется так:

повторить в ячейках диапазона, относящихся к году из первой ячейки столбца, цвет фона ячейки, находящейся на другом листе под ячейкой, содержащей номер искомого года.

Что-то типа горизонтального поиска цвета фона для ячейки F4 на Листе2 среди фонов ячеек B2:M2 диапазона B1:M2 на Листе1, где в ячейках B1:M1 содержатся номера годов 2013-2024:
HLOOKUP(YEAR(F$1);'Лист1'!$B$1:$M$2;2;0)


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

формулами цвет заливки ячейки не скопировать. Вам нужно использовать либо GAS, либо условное форматирование. В таблице, которую вы опубликовали в вопросе, описаны другие "хотелки", помимо той, которую вы опубликовали в вопросе. Определитесь с тем, что конкретно вам нужно и дополните свой вопрос

Предлагаю в подобных таблицах с большим количеством данных использовать условное форматирование градиентом. Например, min величина или 0 имеют красный цвет, max величина - зелёный, а середина с 50% - жёлтый. Это позволит быстро и чётко проанализировать тенденции изменения данных и указать конкретные месяца с значительно отличающимися от большинства величинами. В условном форматировании градиентом есть практическое применение.
